# What site is similar to Critters.org without the commitment?

Tags: reviewing

So, I'd like to post some of my work to the public to get hype and also get some exposure to the public. I have visited [Critters.org](https://critters.org/) and learned that they have a lot of great writers who are looking to get their craft recognized.

However, they require you to submit reviews for at least 75% of the material they present you, or you will not be eligible to have your own material reviewed. I do not have the time or the energy to do that many reviews, as I go to school and work on top of my own writing. What are some other good sites for writer review that doesn't have that kind of commitment? Anything helps!

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this [old locked question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/904/34330)? (There's another [question on meta](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/925/34330) asking the same too.)

Comment: @Laurel That resource question was asked 8 years ago, so I would vote it'd be reasonable to assume the landscape has shifted a bit since then and that this question is therefore not a duplicate. Some new sites have probably proliferated since then. However, the meta question looks like the perfect answer to what OP is looking for - would it be appropriate to replicate some of the linked sites as an answer to this question?

Comment: @Sciborg And have the information in two places? I don't see a reason for that. (For the record, I'm not a fan of historical locks for lists of links; it just creates something that decays over time. I think I need to delete some of the answers to broken sites too.)

Comment: @Laurel Makes sense, sorry.

Comment: I'm with Laurel on this. The meta question is the place to go to: https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/925/where-can-i-get-a-critique-of-my-work

Answer (score 0):

While finding similar websites, one of the best resources is [Similarweb](https://www.similarweb.com/). I would not say that all their results would be accurate, but the entries are based on human inputs, which they try to confirm as best as possible.

You should find some of the resources listed in [this Writer's Digest article](https://www.writersdigest.com/be-inspired/writers-digest-best-writing-community-websites-2020) helpful too.

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly Similarweb answers the OP's question? Is it meant to help them find websites similar to Critters.org?

Comment: OP is in search of a website similar to critters. Similarweb is the #1 website for people searching for similar websites to any website. I just wanted to point him towards the solution.